# SWIFT UIPanGestureRecognizer failed only first time

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

My test app have 4 ScrollView.

1. UIScrollView which can scroll up/down.
2. UIPageViewController inside 1, which can scroll left/right.
3. UITableView inside one of viewController 2, can scroll up/down.
4. UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell on tableView 3, can scroll left/right.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BexX3.jpg

First swipe gesture by UIScrollView 4 causes PageViewController 2 scroll instead. Second and more swipes work correct.

PanGestureRecognizer of UIScrollView 4 has a state "failed" on the first swipe.
`<UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x7f826881fd50; state = Failed; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <Tests.MyCellScroll 0x7f826802f600>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<Tests.MyCellScroll 0x7f826802f600>)>>`

Any ideas what’s the problem or how could it be debugged?

Example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let vcs: [UIViewController] = [
        MyVC(),
        UIViewController()
    ]
    
    private lazy var scroll: UIScrollView = {
        let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        return scroll
    }()
    
    private lazy var pageVC: UIPageViewController = {
        let page = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        page.view.backgroundColor = .white
        page.delegate = self
        page.dataSource = self
        return page
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.addSubview(self.scroll)
        
        self.addChild(self.pageVC)
        self.scroll.addSubview(self.pageVC.view)
        self.pageVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        self.pageVC.setViewControllers([self.vcs[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        self.scroll.frame = self.view.frame
        self.scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + 50)
        self.pageVC.view.frame  = CGRect(x: self.scroll.bounds.minX, y: self.scroll.bounds.minY + 250, width: self.scroll.bounds.width, height: self.scroll.contentSize.height - 250)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        self.vcs.firstIndex(of: viewController) == 1 ? self.vcs[0] : nil
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        self.vcs.firstIndex(of: viewController) == 0 ? self.vcs[1] : nil
    }
}

final class MyVC: UIViewController {
    private lazy var table: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: MyCell.self))
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        return table
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.table)
    }
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        self.table.frame = self.view.frame
    }
}

extension MyVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 5 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { MyCell() }
}

final class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    private lazy var subview: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var scrollView: MyCellScroll = {
        let view = MyCellScroll()
        return view
    }()
    
    init(){
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemOrange.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.subview)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let frame = self.contentView.frame
        
        self.scrollView.frame = frame
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: frame.height)
        
        self.subview.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 8, width: 500 - 32, height: frame.height - 16)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
}


final class MyCellScroll: UIScrollView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        print(gestureRecognizer)
        return false // 5
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating and adding the pan gesture to what!?

Comment: @ElTomato I don't add anything to anywhere. UIScrollView 4 already consists its own UIPanGestureRecognizer. And this inside pangesturerecogniser has a state failed on the first swipe only.